# Don't show data when i click select form = "id=undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, html

Help me please.. it show "`select_modelcar.php?brandid=undefined`" when i choose select form but i try to paste this code in url and define id "`select_modelcar.php?brandid=40`", have the results. i want to choose same categories in select form such as when i choose brand "Toyota", it'll show all car model in Toyota brand (Camry, Yaris, etc.).

### when i click select form >>

[image]

### past in url and define id >>

[image]

### select_brandcar.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<?php $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db("carspecth");
 ?>
 
<body>

<script>
 function ValueID(){
     document.getElementById("getval").innerHTML = ('select_modelcar.php?brandid='+this.value);;
 };
</script>

    <select name="select_brandcar" id="select_brandcar" onclick="ValueID();" >
    <option>Press Choose</option>
    <?php 
   $sql = sprintf ("SELECT * FROM brand" );
    $res = mysql_query ($sql);
   while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
 printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>" ,$arr['brandid'], $arr['brandname']);
 }
   ?>
<span id="getval"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

### select_modelcar.php

```
<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
include 'include_connectdb.php';
@$varbrandid = $_GET['brandid'];
@$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM maingeneration WHERE brandfk = %s", $varbrandid);
/*id ของตาราง catagory*/
@$res = mysql_query($sql);
printf("<select name='select' id='select'>");
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $arr['maingenerationid'], $arr['maingenerationname']);
}
printf("</select>");
?>
```

Comment: Please can you explain clearly what you are trying to achieve and what issues you are experiencing

Comment: I want to choose a car brand Then select the model of the car by select form but it show on the link "select_modelcar.php?brandid=undefined" It should a value, not undefined.

Comment: Try replacing `onclick` with `onchange`

Comment: And if you open the console and look at the generated options, do they all have a value

Comment: you understand my picture?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

Replace `onclick` with `onchange`

Pass the value of the select like this: `onchange='ValueID(this.value);'` 
Then change the function to get that value:

```
function ValueID(brandid){
     document.getElementById("getval").innerHTML = ('select_modelcar.php?brandid='+brandid);;
 };
```

Comment: @PongsakornLaoniyomthai - don't forget it to accept as answer

Comment: I try use id  "getval"  on select form, it show   "select_modelcar.php?brandid=40"  only, not show data from database, help me again plss !!